# obtener valor de una etiqueta html en javascript

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como tomar el texto que tenga en una etiqueta para posteriormente usarla en una variable

```
<tr id="etiqueta">hola</tr>
```

Al parecer con `value` no me funciona con `.value` o `.innerHTMl`

Ojalá alguien me ayude con esto.

Saludos.

Comment: por favor lee [ask], deberás agregar para que no te cierren la pregunta, el código necesario para reproducir el problema

Answer (score 0):

- Value se utiliza para obtener el valor de un input.
- InnerHTML se utiliza para obtener el html contenido dentro de un elemento.
- Lo que creo que estás buscando es [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Te dejo el ejemplo para que lo veas

```js
var a = document.getElementById('saludos');
document.write("<br><br>");


document.write("Texto impreso con innerHTML (se imprime e interpreta la etiqueta span):");
document.write("<br>");
document.write(a.innerHTML);

document.write("<br><br>");
document.write("Texto impreso con textContent (sólo se recoge el texto):");
document.write("<br>");
document.write(a.textContent);
```

```css
span {background-color: #AAA;}
```

```html
<div id="saludos">
Buenos días, <span>buenas tardes</span> y buenas noches.
</div>
```

Comment: por favor espera a que el OP muestre que ha hecho

Comment: @shadow, claro, perdona. No vi tu comentario a tiempo. Lo tengo en cuenta para posteriores veces.

Comment: ya lo prove y efectivamente si funciona(ya me guarda ese valor e imprime en pantalla)..pero por alguna razon me marca error en la consola
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
    at hola
hola  es el nombre de la funcion que llamo al iniciar mi javascript en donde llamo a la etiqueta y despues la imprimo en pantalla
y como dije antes ya funciona pero me extraña que me aparesca esto...sabes porque..? y gracias por tu respuesta.eres un crack--saludos!

Comment: @Juandev puedes poner el código para que veamos mejor que puede estar pasando? (ponlo en tu misma pregunta, por favor. Es decir, editala).